# MYSQL: Order Topics By Latest Comment (comments have topics)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table of topics and I have a table with comments.

**Topics**

```
ID  TOPIC 
1   Guns
2   School
3   Politics
4   War
```

**Comments**

```
DATE       TOPIC     TEXT
5/4/2013   School    'I love school.'
5/5/2013   War       'War sucks.'
5/6/2013   Politics  'I like politics... sometimes.'
5/7/2013   Guns      'I have a few guns. Do you?'
5/8/2013   War       'Stop fighting you guys.'
```

What I need is a MYSQL statement to have this result (in order of most recent comment related to the topic):

```
TOPIC
War
Guns
Politics
School
```

This is a list of the topics ordered by most recent comments about them.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, having the actual topic in the comments table is redundant, as you should just have the topic table id. That way you can alter/modify the topic at anytime, and it will not affect your comments table.

Answer (score 1):

A few recommendations -

1. Change your DATE column format to the MySQL date format `YYYY-mm-dd`
2. Make your TOPIC column a reference to the Topic table ID for that TOPIC

Given those changes, you can do it with this query -

```
SELECT t.`TOPIC` FROM Comments c 
JOIN Topics t ON t.ID = c.`TOPIC`
GROUP BY c.`TOPIC`
ORDER BY MAX(`DATE`) DESC
```

you can see this SQLFiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02560/1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `topic` = 'War' ORDER BY `date`
UNION
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `topic` = 'Guns' ORDER BY `date`
UNION
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `topic` = 'Politics' ORDER BY `date`
UNION
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `topic` = 'School' ORDER BY `date`
```

Not really the mother of efficiency but will work..

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this query:

```
SELECT t.topic FROM Comments c 
INNER JOIN Topics t ON t.topic = c.topic
GROUP BY c.topic
ORDER BY c.date DESC
```

**I suggest to add these:**

- change date format as per MYSQL.
- use topic id for reference instead of topic.